# XPath index selector returning the entire array, instead of the element at the index

Tags: selenium, xpath

For some reason, putting index in XPath is returning the entire array of objects, and not the one at the index

**The HTML**

The HTML I'm working on looks like this:

```
<ul id="permission-list" style="padding-top:0px">

    <li id="10-list-item" data-model="{&quot;Id&quot;:10,&quot;Name&quot;:&quot;General&quot;,&quot;GroupName&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;DescStr&quot;:&quot; &quot;,&quot;Type&quot;:0}" class="topLevel">
        <i onclick="ExpandableIcon(this)" href="#collapse-10" data-toggle="collapse" class="fa permission-collapse clickable fa-minus-square-o" aria-hidden="true" aria-expanded="true"></i> - 
        <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0">
            <input onchange="PermissionCheckOnChange(this,15)" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="">
            <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
        </label> General (
        <span class="selected-permission">0</span> of 6 )
        <blockquote class="blockquote permission-description">
            <p class="mb-0" style=" color: #5d9cc3;">

            </p>
        </blockquote>
        <ul class="permission-item-list collapse show" id="collapse-10" style="">

            <li id="10100-list-item" data-model="{&quot;Id&quot;:10100,&quot;Name&quot;:&quot;System&quot;,&quot;GroupName&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;DescStr&quot;:&quot;General System Permissions&quot;,&quot;Type&quot;:0}">

                <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0">
                    <input onchange="PermissionCheckOnChange(this,15)" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="">
                    <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
                </label> System 
                <blockquote class="blockquote permission-description">
                    <p class="mb-0" style=" color: #5d9cc3;">
                        General System Permissions
                    </p>
                </blockquote>
                <ul class="collapse permission-item-list" id="collapse-10100">

                </ul>
            </li>

            <li id="10500-list-item" data-model="{&quot;Id&quot;:10500,&quot;Name&quot;:&quot;Printer&quot;,&quot;GroupName&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;DescStr&quot;:&quot;Printer's permissions&quot;,&quot;Type&quot;:0}">

                <i onclick="ExpandableIcon(this)" href="#collapse-10500" data-toggle="collapse" class="fa permission-collapse clickable fa-minus-square-o" aria-hidden="true" aria-expanded="true"></i> - 
                <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0" id="checkboxOfInterest">
                    <input onchange="PermissionCheckOnChange(this,15)" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="">
                    <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
                </label> Printer (
                <span class="selected-permission">0</span> of 4 )
                <blockquote class="blockquote permission-description">
                    <p class="mb-0" style=" color: #5d9cc3;">
                        Printer's permissions
                    </p>
                </blockquote>
                <ul class="permission-item-list collapse show" id="collapse-10500" style="">

                    <li id="1050001-list-item" data-model="{&quot;Id&quot;:1050001,&quot;Name&quot;:&quot;Add New Printer&quot;,&quot;GroupName&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;DescStr&quot;:&quot;Add Printer&quot;,&quot;Type&quot;:0}">
                        <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0">
                            <input onchange="PermissionCheckOnChange(this,15)" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="">
                            <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
                        </label> Add New Printer 
                        <blockquote class="blockquote permission-description">
                            <p class="mb-0" style=" color: #5d9cc3;">
                                Add Printer
                            </p>
                        </blockquote>
                    </li>

                    <li id="1050002-list-item" data-model="{&quot;Id&quot;:1050002,&quot;Name&quot;:&quot;Edit Printer&quot;,&quot;GroupName&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;DescStr&quot;:&quot;Edit Printer&quot;,&quot;Type&quot;:0}">
                        <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0">
                            <input onchange="PermissionCheckOnChange(this,15)" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="">
                            <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
                        </label> Edit Printer 
                        <blockquote class="blockquote permission-description">
                            <p class="mb-0" style=" color: #5d9cc3;">
                                Edit Printer
                            </p>
                        </blockquote>
                    </li>

                    <li id="1050003-list-item" data-model="{&quot;Id&quot;:1050003,&quot;Name&quot;:&quot;Delete Printer&quot;,&quot;GroupName&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;DescStr&quot;:&quot;Delete Printer&quot;,&quot;Type&quot;:0}">
                        <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0">
                            <input onchange="PermissionCheckOnChange(this,15)" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="">
                            <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
                        </label> Delete Printer 
                        <blockquote class="blockquote permission-description">
                            <p class="mb-0" style=" color: #5d9cc3;">
                                Delete Printer
                            </p>
                        </blockquote>
                    </li>

                    <li id="1050010-list-item" data-model="{&quot;Id&quot;:1050010,&quot;Name&quot;:&quot;Print&quot;,&quot;GroupName&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;DescStr&quot;:&quot;it's value contains the list of levels which can use to print&quot;,&quot;Type&quot;:0}">
                        <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0">
                            <input onchange="PermissionCheckOnChange(this,15)" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="">
                            <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
                        </label> Print 
                        <blockquote class="blockquote permission-description">
                            <p class="mb-0" style=" color: #5d9cc3;">
                                it's value contains the list of levels which can use to print
                            </p>
                        </blockquote>
                    </li>

                </ul>
            </li>

        </ul>
    </li>

    <li id="50-list-item" data-model="{&quot;Id&quot;:50,&quot;Name&quot;:&quot;POS&quot;,&quot;GroupName&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;DescStr&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;Type&quot;:0}" class="topLevel">
        <i onclick="ExpandableIcon(this)" href="#collapse-50" data-toggle="collapse" class="fa permission-collapse clickable fa-minus-square-o" aria-hidden="true" aria-expanded="true"></i> - 
        <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0">
            <input onchange="PermissionCheckOnChange(this,15)" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="">
            <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
        </label> POS (
        <span class="selected-permission">0</span> of 2 )
        <blockquote class="blockquote permission-description">
            <p class="mb-0" style=" color: #5d9cc3;">

            </p>
        </blockquote>
        <ul class="permission-item-list collapse show" id="collapse-50" style="">

            <li id="50100-list-item" data-model="{&quot;Id&quot;:50100,&quot;Name&quot;:&quot;General&quot;,&quot;GroupName&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;DescStr&quot;:&quot;General POS Permissions&quot;,&quot;Type&quot;:0}">

                <i onclick="ExpandableIcon(this)" href="#collapse-50100" data-toggle="collapse" class="fa fa-plus-square-o permission-collapse clickable" aria-hidden="true"></i> - 
                <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0">
                    <input onchange="PermissionCheckOnChange(this,15)" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="">
                    <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
                </label> General (
                <span class="selected-permission">0</span> of 1 )
                <blockquote class="blockquote permission-description">
                    <p class="mb-0" style=" color: #5d9cc3;">
                        General POS Permissions
                    </p>
                </blockquote>
                <ul class="collapse permission-item-list" id="collapse-50100">

                    <li id="5010010-list-item" data-model="{&quot;Id&quot;:5010010,&quot;Name&quot;:&quot;POS Login&quot;,&quot;GroupName&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;DescStr&quot;:&quot;Login into pos&quot;,&quot;Type&quot;:0}">
                        <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0">
                            <input onchange="PermissionCheckOnChange(this,15)" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="">
                            <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
                        </label> POS Login 
                        <blockquote class="blockquote permission-description">
                            <p class="mb-0" style=" color: #5d9cc3;">
                                Login into pos
                            </p>
                        </blockquote>
                    </li>

                </ul>
            </li>

        </ul>
    </li>

</ul>
```

**Screenshot of the HTML**

Here's a screenshot of the HTML, simplified. [image]

**What I'm trying to do**

I'm trying to write Selenium test against the checkboxes. Checking a leaf checkbox should only check that leaf checkbox, and checking a parent checkbox should also check the child checkboxes.

**My XPath selector**

In that code, I placed an ID on one of the fields, for ease of XPath selector writing, in the Developer Console. This one in particular:

```
<label class="custom-control custom-checkbox mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0" id="checkboxOfInterest">
    <input onchange="PermissionCheckOnChange(this,15)" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="">
    <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
</label>
```

My full XPath selector, on the container containing what I want, then becomes

```
id("checkboxOfInterest")/ancestor::li//ul[contains(concat(" ", @class, " "), " permission-item-list ")][1]
```

**Expectation**

I expect this to be returned at the Developer Console:

```
ul#collapse-10500.permission-item-list.collapse.show
```

**Reality**

Instead, I get the following Array:

```
[ul#collapse-10500.permission-item-list.collapse.show, ul#collapse-10.permission-item-list.collapse.show, ul#collapse-10100.collapse.permission-item-list]
```

Sorry this is long-winded, but can someone guide me to why it's doing this and what my options are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get clear concept of `context position` and `document order` involved in XPath Axis as following:

[image]

You can find above note from [W3C XPATH Specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-xpath-31-20170321/#axes)

To solve your issue, you can try `id("checkboxOfInterest")/ancestor::li[1]//ul`

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try -

```
id("checkboxOfInterest")/ancestor::li/ul[contains(@class, "permission-item-list ")][1]
```

Comment: Is your nested by any chance i.e. it's returning single element only but the hierarchy turns out like that?

Answer (score 0):

A predicate [1] applies to the last step in your expression, not to the expression as a whole. For example, `x/y[1]` will return the first `y` child of every `x`. If you only want the first item in the result of the expression `x/y`, use parentheses: `(x/y)[1]`.